# Case when inside VB.net query

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Machine_Master(Machine_Code,Machine_Name,Status)" _
    & " VALUES ('" & textmachinecode.Text & "','" & textdescription.Text & "', '" & combostatus.Text & "')"
```

How to change text from combobox? When it's saved in database it will be integer. In this case, text `combostatus.Text` *active* will be 1 when saved and *not active* will be 0.

Comment: I recommend you to use parametrized parameters to do the query, specially when using user-introduced text fields. To avoid SQL Injection attacks and other potential errors

Answer (score 2):

As Patrick said, you don't need `case when` since you can do that on the vb.net side, but you should use parameters to avoid problems:

```
Dim result As String = String.Empty
sql = "INSERT INTO Machine_Master (Machine_Code,Machine_Name,Status) " & _
      " VALUES (@CODE, @DESC, @STATUS)"

Using cn As New SqlConnection("connectionString"), cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
    Dim status As Integer = -1

    Select Case combostatus.Text.ToLower()
        Case "active" : status = 1
        Case "not active" : status = 0
    End Select

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", textmachinecode.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESC", textdescription.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", status)

    result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `case when`, you could simple solve this client side (mind that using parameters is better, as already suggested!)

Use this condition:

```
IIf(combostatus.Text = "active", 1, 0)
```

So, totally it becomes:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Machine_Master(Machine_Code,Machine_Name,Status)" _
      & " VALUES ('" & textmachinecode.Text & "','" & textdescription.Text & "', " _ 
      & IIf(combostatus.Text = "active", 1, 0) & ")"
```

Comment: Since you are new: if your question was resolved by one of the answers, check the check mark before the answer you liked most. It will remove your question from the unanswered list.

Comment: Maybe is `IIf()` instead of `If()`?

Comment: how to create report base on datagrid ?? in case after we select data into datagrid , how to make it into crystal report ??